# Horizontal and vertical output from same SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure this can be done, and tried numerous searches but no real result yet.

I have a SQL Server database with a table where I want to output results from a single table both horizontally and vertically.  I realise this will be a complex SQL statement and have managed part of the vertical using a UNION but the horizontal eludes me.

The table has a field called "reference" and contains a string of characters such as "A03ACCEVEN18JS-SN1AA" or "A02ACCVCOM18JS-FN1AA". I want to create an output with a row for the count of references commencing A02 then a row for A03, A04 etc that also contain "18".  Then expand horizontally to count the references with different letters after the hyphen, i.e. "-s" and "-f" etc.  So the output would look like below,

```
               S_Count | F_Count | J_Count etc
               ---------------------------------
A02 Row -->      58    |   23    |    16
A03 Row -->      22    |   43    |    53
A04 Row -->      7     |   31    |    23
etc
```

I managed to get  one column so far with multiple where clauses and UNIONS like below but I now need the vertical.  Can this be done please?

```
SELECT COUNT(reference) FROM mytable
WHERE reference LIKE 'A02%' AND reference LIKE '%%18%%' AND PATINDEX('%-P%', 
reference) <> 0
UNION
SELECT COUNT(reference) FROM mytable
WHERE reference LIKE 'A03%' AND reference LIKE '%%18%%' AND PATINDEX('%-P%', 
reference) <> 0
UNION
SELECT COUNT(reference) AS TOTAL FROM mytable
WHERE reference LIKE 'A04%' AND reference LIKE '%%18%%' AND PATINDEX('%-P%', 
reference) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do it all in one hit :)

```
SELECT
    LEFT(reference, 3) as ao_number,
    SUM(CASE WHEN reference LIKE '%-S%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as s_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN reference LIKE '%-F%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as j_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN reference LIKE '%-J%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as s_count
FROM
    table
WHERE
    reference like 'A0%18%'
GROUP BY
    LEFT(reference, 3)
```

Notes:

`LEFT(reference, 3)` pulls the A0x number off the start. Grouping by this will give us one row per distinct A0x number, so if a thousand variations of A00 to A09 are present, we'll get 10 rows

You don't need to (and shouldn't) say `WHERE reference LIKE 'A03%' AND reference LIKE '%%18%%'` etc.. I just combine them to 'A0%18%'. Note that I didn't combine them to 'A03%18%' as that would restrict our data too much. Don't double up your percent signs when doing a like

The SUM performs a count; the case when looks a the reference and if it has e.g. an -S in it, then it returns 1 else 0. Summing these effectively counts the reference patterns

By th way, for future searching purposes, this type of query is called a PIVOT. Most databases have some proprietary syntax to carry out pivoting, but I tend to remember/utilize this pattern because it's a bit more flexible and is cross-db compatible

Comment: Thanks for this.  It works.  I had been trying a few self joins for the horizontal element but that didn't seem to work.  I might try and add a totals column too.